# How Can we integrate JQuery with windows XP Desktop?

Tags: jquery, windows-xp, windows-desktop-gadgets

How Can we integrate a JQuery menu with windows XP desktop for example a top menu that appears on mouse over ...

Comment: Why would you want to use jQuery for a desktop application? jQuery is javascript - a **browser** script language.

Comment: What sort of question is this, Javascript for Windows Desktop lol

Comment: @Tomas: JavaScript is  *typically* used in browsers, but there's nothing that prevents it from being used elsewhere. jQuery however, is a framework primarily designed to manipulate a DOM which might not be present in desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Desktop Gadgets are written using XML/HTML and Javascript/VbScript. As are HTA (HTML Applications). I had to use an HTA to solve a rather unfortunate problem once and the only thing that kept me sane was that I could use jQuery.

Comment: How can we do something like this : http://www.jquerylightbox.com/jquerylightbox.jpg ?

get it here :
http://www.rocketdownload.com/program/visual-jquery-lightbox-154806.html

Comment: Well you could either: write a .net application that uses a WebBrowser control to render, and inject its contents from code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx ; or you could write that application as an HTA, not sure that you would be able to encompass all the features indicated on that screen-shot but probably. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx